# Is there a way to access Apache Solr (8.3.1) search queries without crawling the logs?

Tags: solr

For statistic purposes I have to save and analyse all search queries made to a server running Solr (version 8.3.1). Maybe it's just because I haven't worked with Solr until today, but I couldn't find a simpler way to access these queries except crawling the logs.

I've only found one article to help me, in which the following is stated:

> I think that solr by him self doesn't store the queries (correct me if I'm wrong, about this) but you can accomplish what you want by processing the solr log (its the only way I think).

(source: https://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/is-it-possible-to-save-the-search-query-td4018925.html)

Is there any more convenient way to do this?

Comment: Use a separate database for that. Check https://cassandra.apache.org/, it has very good write performance.

Comment: No, not as far as I know. Parsing the logs is still the way to go (and can be done completely offline without affecting performance).

Comment: @KiraLT I'm not seeking for a way to store the queries. Perhaps I misphrased my question. I'm looking for a more convenient way to get the queries out of Solr and into an established database. I did not find any other way for that than working with the logs though.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for the clarification. I was wondering because I didn't find any official documentation for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a good way to achieve this in another SO-Question. Well, at least kind of.

**Note:** It is only useful if you have enough resources on the same server or another server to properly handle a second Solr-Core.

[Link to original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36653541/14945497)

That SO-Question is about Elastic-Search but the methodology of it can also be applied to this case with a second Solr-Core that indexes the queries made. (One can also add additional fields like when it was last searched, total search count, ...)
The functionalities of a search auto-complete are also achievable with this solution.

**In short:**
The basic idea is to use a second Solr instance to provide the means necessary for quickly saving the queries (instead of a DB for instance).

**Remark:** I'm not going to accept this as the best answer because it is a rather special solution to the question I originally made. But I nonetheless felt it could be useful for any programmer trying to achieve this while also thinking about search auto-completion.